# MongoDB aggregation $substr from end of string?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, substr

I have an _id of the form:

```
'london_24:2016-09-09 23'
```

This maps to `device name:date date_hour`. Since the device name length can vary, I can't use $substr in the conventional way - I need to output just the `device name:date`.

Ideally I'd like to $substr from the end of the string, but the documentation doesn't seem to allow for this. What other methods can I use to achieve this?

EDIT: I'm running MongoDB 3.2 on production - is there any current way of doing this without having to upgrade to 3.3, which is development version only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MongoDB 3.4 you can use [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) operator for strings. This should work since I can split on the space and return the first part.